# pythonbrew importing bz2 yields: ImportError: No module named '_bz2'

Tags: python, debian, raspberry-pi, bzip2, pythonbrew

This wtf happens on a Debian, during some dumb pip install, in python3.4.1

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-3.4.1/lib/python3.4/tarfile.py", line 1640, in bz2open
    import bz2
  File "/home/pi/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-3.4.1/lib/python3.4/bz2.py", line 20, in <module>
    from _bz2 import BZ2Compressor, BZ2Decompressor
ImportError: No module named '_bz2'
```

Unless someone nails this early & easy, I will return next year to emblandish it with boredom like which RaspberryPI Debian it is.

Anyhoozle, the junior answer is `apt-get install libbz2-dev` tx to @falsetru for finishing the FAQ segments of tonight's entertainment. However, we seem to have `aptitude install`ed a bunch of random filenames ending in `-dev` recently:

```
$ aptitude search libbz2
i   libbz2-1.0    
i   libbz2-dev
```

So now I gotta make the question harder. If I guess the RaspberryPi itself is not at fault (this sh*t swings like Tarzan on my WinPython3.3, 64-beet), then maybe `pythonbrew` dunnit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install [`libbz2-dev` package](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libbz2-dev) before install Python to build [`bz2` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bz2.html).

```
apt-get install libbz2-dev
```

Comment: thanks from the community - SEO will now match the above error message to standard channels, so anyone with the error message gets the exact answer. This is only not the correct answer from the page bc "we must go deeper." I installed that library package a while ago by reflex, hence something else in my stack (django17, Raspbian, RPI, pythonbrew, python3.4.1, etc.) must be at fault.

Comment: What happens if you already had Python installed?

Answer (score 1):

The "winning" answer is to erase your .pythonbrew folder and build again. Put another way, Python had trouble seeing Aptitude -dev packages installed after pythonbrew built it.

Nobody upvote it plz, bc it's still just a sucky workaround!